# Firebase rule query.equalTo always returns "Permission denied" on REST

Tags: rest, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm trying to get my database secure and my scenario data looks like:

```
receipts: [
  {
    userId: id,
    ...
  },
  {
    userId: id,
    ...
  },
...
]
```

Each receipt has `userId` field with information about it's creator. I would like to return list of receipts for specific user. For that I've made REST call which looks like this:

`https://[PROJ_NAME].firebaseio.com/receipts.json?orderBy="userId"&equalTo="[USER_ID]"&auth=[TOKEN]`

And on all rules set to open it works great. But I would like to protect my database so other users cannot see all resources just by changing URL.

On firebase documentation I've found such snippet:

```
"baskets": {
  ".read": "auth.uid != null &&
            query.orderByChild == 'owner' &&
            query.equalTo == auth.uid" // restrict basket access to owner of basket
}
```

It seems reasonable so I applyed it to my configuration but now it always fails. This is how my file looks like:

```
{
  "rules": {
      "receipts": {
        ".indexOn": ["userId"],
        ".read": "auth.uid != null &&
                  query.orderByChild == 'userId' &&
                  query.equalTo == auth.uid"
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately it always returns `"error" : "Permission denied"`. I've lost whole day because of that thing :(

Can anyone help me pls?

Comment: Have you tried quoting the `equalTo` value? e.g. `equalTo="[USERID]"`

Comment: Yes, it is quoted same as `orderBy="userId"`.

Comment: I don't find anything in the [security rules documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/) about the `query` variable.  I don't think the terms in your rule that use `query` are valid.  Can you post a link to the docs or examples you found that use `query` in rules?

Comment: @BobSnyder: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#query_based_rules I didn't even know this had been released, so will need a moment to catch up... and possibly update a few hundred questions to explains that "rules can now be used to filter data, if you make sure the query and rule agree".

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: After more research I deleted my comment.  The OP said the query works with "open" security rules, so I figured I was mistaken.

Comment: @Koper: I'm having a hard time securing my queries even with the JavaScript SDK, so I'm asking around.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen @BobSnyder It even works when I have rules like `".read": "auth.uid != null && query.orderByChild == 'userId'"` so it looks like the issue occurs because of equalTo `query.equalTo == auth.uid`. Maybe there is something wrong with the comparison? I don't know how I could debug it.

Comment: Based on tests I've done using the Android SDK, I agree that `equalTo` seems to be broken.

Comment: The bugfix has just been pushed into production. I tested with just `equalTo` and it works, so the workaround should no longer be needed. Thanks for reporting this problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*firebaser here*

Update (2018-01-25): This bug has now been fixed. Since this was a server-side issue, there is no need to update your SDKs.

.

---

*Original answer below*

---

There is a bug in the way the server interprets security rules that use `query.orderByChild` and `query.equalTo` at the moment. We're working on a fix.

To work around the problem for now, you can combine `query.startAt` and `query.endAt` to get the same result:

```
    ".read": "auth.uid != null &&
              query.orderByChild == 'userId' &&
              query.startAt == auth.uid &&
              query.endAt == auth.uid"
```

Comment: Great! This workaround works as expected. I didn't even have to change my query. Above rule works with `equalTo` in query URL.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that it works with the same query. I'm immediately trying to see if there's an exploit there. :-) Let me know if you find one! Or if you find more problems of course.

Comment: this always returns null for me even though I have data for the same uid

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I think I'm seeing a similar permission denied [bug with the startAt rule in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59434528/query-startat-database-rule-permission-denied)