# query.startAt database rule permission denied

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Seems like either the `query.startAt` rule is broken, or I don't understand it. Can someone confirm? Here is the minimal reproducible error. [Live example](https://querystartaterror.firebaseapp.com/); open Chrome console with CTRL+SHIFT+i. [GitHub repo](https://github.com/ChrisChiasson/queryStartAtError).

database.rules.json:

```
{
 "rules":{
  ".read": "query.startAt>0",
  ".write": false
 }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <script src="/__/firebase/7.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
 <script src="/__/firebase/7.6.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
 <script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
 <script>
  function init(){
   firebase.database.enableLogging(true);
   const db=firebase.database();
   const qry=db.ref("/").orderByChild('time').startAt(3);
   //logging shows permission denied on next line
   qry.once('value',s=>console.log("snapshot",s.val()));
  }

  init();
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

database contents:

[image: database contents]

Chrome browser console output shows permission denied:

```
...snip...
@firebase/database: p:0: Listen on / for {"i":"time","sp":3} 
@firebase/database: p:0: {"r":2,"a":"q","b":{"p":"/","q":{"sp":3,"i":"time"},"t":1,"h":""}} 
...snip...
@firebase/database: p:0: from server: {"r":2,"b":{"s":"permission_denied","d":"Permission denied"}} 
@firebase/database: p:0: listen response {"s":"permission_denied","d":"Permission denied"} 
@firebase/database: event: /:cancel
```

If database.rules.json is changed to:

```
{
 "rules":{
  ".read": true,
  ".write": false
 }
}
```

The permission denial of the listen disappears from the browser console:

```
...snip...
@firebase/database: p:0: Listen on / for {"i":"time","sp":3} 
@firebase/database: p:0: {"r":2,"a":"q","b":{"p":"/","q":{"sp":3,"i":"time"},"t":1,"h":""}} 
...snip...
@firebase/database: p:0: handleServerMessage d {"p":"","d":{"msg1":{"time":11}}} 
@firebase/database: event: /:value:{"msg1":{"time":11}} 
01:45:21.044 (index):13 snapshot {"msg1":{"time":11}}
@firebase/database: p:0: from server: {"r":2,"b":{"s":"ok","d":{"w":["no_index"]}}} 
...snip...
```

This was reduced from a larger application, where it manifested with logged in users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*firebaser here*

I can reproduce this problem, and as far as I can see your rules look fine.

In my testing, when using `query.startAt == 3` the rules correctly allow the read, but using `>` or `>=` the rules reject the read operation.

Can you [file a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) to see if this is a bug in the rules module, or if we're both missing something about your rules?

---

Update: the problem seems to come from a misinterpretation of types in the rules engine. For example, when you ensure all numbers are floating point it works:

```
".read": "query.startAt > 0.5",
```

And:

```
ref.orderByChild("time").startAt(2.5);
```

Note that this is just part of troubleshooting, and not meant to be a solution, although it may allow you to work around the problem for the moment.

Comment: I didn't even know you could filter by query. Learn something new every day.

Comment: Report filed as requested

Comment: seems like this issue still exist in 2022, is there a link to the bug report? has there been any feedback from the firebase team? thanks in advance.

Comment: @B12Toaster I don't remember them getting back to me with "this is fixed", so probably not. If there is a public bug board for something like the rules engine (as opposed to the sdks on Github) I would appreciate a link. Frank's workaround did help me though, since it could be used to explicitly cast to a floating point number close to the integer.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisChiasson for your reply. I'm also not aware of any public bugboard for Firebase Realtime db. However, you are right, Frank's workaround solved this problem for now. Many thanks for your guys' input!